# Problem with MPLAB's toolsuite

Tags: mplab, proteus

I'm taking a module at University that involves MPLab. I'm trying to get it setup at home and so far its been a little tricky. I've got my files from University which I've attached below - if there any help in regards to finding out what language toolsuite I need to use, then that would be great. If it helps, when I use the Project Wizard the device that it gives me is: `PIC24FJ128GA010`

**Version:** MPLAB IDE v8.87

**My current issue with MPLAB**

Each time I try build my files that I've attached, all I get is **Build Failed**. For my debugger I'm using Proteus VSM 7.8. I believe it's a compiler error - I don't believe I've got the correct compiler setup, or even setup a compiler at all.

Test Files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sekuzv92jsjpaht/testFiles.rar (these work fine on the University computers but when I try build from home it just fails).

I'm sorry if this is a little vague but I'm very new to MPLAB but I'd like to learn more of its features so I'm trying to get it working at home. I apologise in advance if I've not included the correct information and/or missed anything out, if I have, I'll add it as soon as possible. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .map file that's part of the bundle you shared shows that the Microchip C30 compiler was used to build this project. Unfortunately I don't see what version of C30, but at least the compiler is known.

```
c:/program files/microchip/mplab c30/bin/../lib\libpic30-coff.a(crt1.o)
                          (_resetALT)
c:/program files/microchip/mplab c30/bin/../lib\libpic30-coff.a(crt0.o)
                          (_resetPRI)
Program Memory Usage
```

There's a free version of C30 (no optimization) that can be downloaded and installed from Microchip's website. Give the latest version a try and see what happens.